# How to use play-json format/reads/writes macro with tagged types

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I use typesafe tags in my models.

Tags API:

```
/** Tag of type `U`. */
type Tag[+U] = { type Tag <: U }
/** Type `T` tagged with tag of type `U`. */
type @@[T, +U] = T with Tag[U]

implicit class Taggable[T](val t: T) extends AnyVal {
  /** Tag with type `U`. */
  def tag[U]: T @@ U = t.asInstanceOf[T @@ U]
  /** Tag with type `U`. */
  def @@[U]: T @@ U = tag[U]
}
```

Example model:

```
case class User(id: Long @@ User, name: String)
```

The problem is: invocation of *play-json*'s `Json.format` macro not compile when there is a tagged type in the case class:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

implicit val userIdFormat: Format[Long @@ User] = ???
Json.format[User] // doesn't compile
```

`Error:(22, 14) type mismatch;
found   : id.type (with underlying type com.artezio.util.tags.User)
required: com.artezio.util.tags.@@[Long,com.artezio.util.tags.User]
   (which expands to)  Long with AnyRef{type Tag <: com.artezio.util.tags.User}`

But all goes smoothly if I create `Format` instance manually:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

implicit val userIdFormat: Format[Long @@ User] = ???
implicit val userFormat: Format[User] = (
  (JsPath \ "id").format[Long @@ User] and
  (JsPath \ "name").format[String]
)(User.apply, unlift(User.unapply))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can call it a bug, or perhaps a missing feature. You can use a compiler flag to see the generated code of the macro. `scalacOptions ++= Seq("-Ymacro-debug-verbose")`

What you get is (with `Reads` instead of `Format`):

```
{
  import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._;
  final class $anon extends play.api.libs.json.util.LazyHelper[Reads, User] {
    def <init>() = {
      super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    override lazy val lazyStuff: Reads[User] = play.api.libs.json.JsPath.$bslash("id").lazyRead(this.lazyStuff).and(play.api.libs.json.JsPath.$bslash("name").read(json.this.Reads.StringReads)).apply(((id, name) => User.apply(id, name)))
  };
  new $anon()
}.lazyStuff
```

Simplified for readability:

```
{
  import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
  final class $anon extends play.api.libs.json.util.LazyHelper[Reads, User] {
    override lazy val lazyStuff: Reads[User] = {
      (__ \ ("id")).lazyRead(this.lazyStuff)
      .and((__ \ ("name")).read(Reads.StringReads))
      .apply(((id, name) => User.apply(id, name)))    
    }

  }
  new $anon()
}.lazyStuff
```

Notice the recursive call `(__ \ ("id")).lazyRead(this.lazyStuff)`, which is a `Reads[User]`. For some reason, `id` is inferred as having type `User` within the macro, which causes the wrong `Reads` to be called, and you get the type mismatch on macro expansion.

Answer (score 3):

Play-json format macro doesn't support tagged types, but you can provide `Json.format` for your tagged type yourself. (Examples are using `scalaz.Tag`, but idea is the same for other implementations).

If your are tagging `Long` type you can use this:

```
implicit def taggedLongFormat[T]: Format[Long @@ T] = new Format[Long @@ T] {
  def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Long @@ T] = json match {
    case JsNumber(v) => JsSuccess(Tag.of[T](v.toLong))
    case unknown => JsError(s"Number value expected, got: $unknown")
  }
  def writes(v: Long @@ T): JsValue = JsNumber(Tag.unwrap(v))
}
```

Or if you are tagging `String` type you can use this:

```
implicit def taggedStringFormat[T]: Format[String @@ T] = new Format[String @@ T] {
  def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[String @@ T] = json match {
    case JsString(v) => JsSuccess(Tag.of[T](v))
    case unknown => JsError(s"String value expected, got: $unknown")
  }
  def writes(v: String @@ T): JsValue = JsString(Tag.unwrap(v))
}
```

Now `format` for every `case class` containing tagged type can be created directly:

```
implicit val userFormat = Json.format[User]
```

Comment: I do provide format for tagged type, just omitted its impl for brevity. Does your code compile? If so, the difference might be in tagged types impl details.

Comment: Yes, it compiles. Here is complete example: https://gist.github.com/VlachJosef/c09ac88998589ad79244

Comment: Okay, I see. I don't like Scalaz tags, due to their (in)variance and inability to treat, e.g. tagged `Long` as a ... `Long`.

Comment: Maybe shapeless tags would suit your use case batter. You can treat tagged `Long` as a `Long`. Here is gist with shapeless tags https://gist.github.com/VlachJosef/0ca136702a7cd4af1032

Comment: Thanks, will check out how Shapeless' implementation differs from mine to find a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

After some investigation it turned out that the problem was caused by using a 'recursive' type in the tag position, e.g.:

```
case class User(userId: Long @@ User)
```

It doesn't work neither with my tags API nor with Shapeless' (suspect the same with Scalaz tags, though I didn't try).

So the workaround for me was to use a separate type for tags, like:

```
sealed trait U
case class User(userId: Long @@ U)
```